# If I have an index.html.erb that has no AR calls, does it make sense to cache?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, performance, caching, ruby-on-rails-4

I am using Rails 4.1, and my `index.html.erb` doesn't contain any instance variables or anything from ActiveRecord.

It does have some path_helper_tags and a few other Rails calls - but no database queries.

In an attempt to speed up the loading, should I use actionpack caching? Or does it not make sense in my case?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

If no before_filters, such as login, are required, try using [`page caching`](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/v2.3.11/caching_with_rails.html). it is super fast and easy to implement.

Use `action caching` if you have `before_filters`